# PHP Get all numerical/anonymous keys in an array

Tags: php, arrays, key, anonymous

I have a multidimensional array, I am interested in getting all the elements (one level deep) that don't have named keys.

i.e.

```
Array
{
  ['settings'] {...}
  ['something'] {...}
  [0] {...} // I want this one
  ['something_else'] {...}
  [1] {...} // And this one
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one way

```
foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
 if(is_int($key)) {
  //do something
 }
}
```

EDIT

Depending on the size of your array it may be faster and more memory efficient to do this instead. It does however require that the keys are in order and none are missing.

```
for($i=0;isset($array[$i]);$i++){
 //do something
}
```

Comment: awesome that worked thanks for your help :) (will accept when i can)

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($initial_array as $key => $value)
  if ( ! is_string( $key ) )
    $result[ $key ] = $value;
```

Comment: thanks that should also work but tecent answered first - thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The key is `0`, Shouldn't be `$your_array[0]`?

Comment: Yep but I could have many of these elements mixed in with named ones and I am unsure how many